# notation in congruence relation

Tags: notation, ideals, congruence-relations, polynomial-rings

hi there i was looking through my lecture notes and i'm struggling to understand a particular piece of notation the vertical line | and i was wondering if you could explain its meaning

$$f \sim g \iff f - g \text{ is an element of } (x^2)  \iff x^2|f-g$$

where $f$ and $g$ are elements of polynomial ring $R[x]$ and
$(x^2)$  is an ideal s.t. $\{f\cdot x^2 \text{ is an element of } R[x] \mid f \text{ is an element of } R[x]\}$

see i understand the second use of | but not the first. could anyone explain the meaning to me please

Comment: What is the first use of $|$? That $x^2\mid f(x)-g(x)$? This means that $x^2$ divides $f(x)-g(x)$.

Comment: The first means "divides evenly".

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Oh, I just meant "divides".    In English we often say things like $3$ divides $9$ evenly, to distinguish it from situations like $\frac 83\in \mathbb Q$.

Comment: I see, "a divides b *evenly*", e.g., [here](https://www.beatthegmat.com/what-do-they-mean-by-dividing-evenly-t118490.html). I was confused by the word "even" (to divide oddly)

Comment: @DietrichBurde  exactly.  Here "evenly" has nothing to do with parity...it's "even" in the sense of uniform or fair.  As in, "you have a bunch of toys and you wish to distribute them to the kids evenly."

Answer (score 2):

The first use means 'divides' — thus, there is a polynomial $h(x)$ such that $f(x)-g(x) = x^2h(x)$.

Also, to ensure proper spacing use the `\mid` command; e.g., $x^2 \mid f(x) - g(x)$.

Finally, since $x$ is being used as a variable, it's a good idea to write $f(x)$ instead of $f$ in this context since the polynomial $x^2$ doesn't have a name.

Comment: I prefer to use the colon  :  instead of the vertical line in set-notation, especially if I've already used it for "divides".